# substraction in typescript returns Undefined

Tags: javascript, typescript

I am new to typescript and trying to execute below code snippet :-

```
class TestClass
{
  public  t: number = 10;

  public TestClass()
   {
    this.t = this.t - 1;
    console.log(this.t);
   }
}

var obj = new TestClass();
```

Here is the link to [playground](http://www.typescriptlang.org/play/#src=%0D%0Aclass%20testClass%0D%0A%7B%0D%0A%20%20public%20%20t%3A%20number%20%3D%2010%3B%0D%0A%0D%0A%20%20%20public%20testClass()%0D%0A%20%20%20%20%7B%0D%0A%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20this.t%20%3D%20this.t%20-%201%3B%0D%0A%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20console.log(this.t)%3B%0D%0A%20%20%20%20%7D%0D%0A%7D%0D%0A%0D%0Avar%20obj%20%3D%20new%20testClass()%3B)

The snippet(when transpiled to JavaScript) prints Undefined in chrome developer console whereas I expect it to print 9.

Could someone please help me explain the behavior in both typescript and javascript

Comment: use `obj.testClass();`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Since you declare the `console.log` part in a public method, you need to run `obj.TestClass()`.

[playground](https://www.typescriptlang.org/play/#src=%0D%0Aclass%20testClass%0D%0A%7B%0D%0A%20%20public%20%20t%3A%20number%20%3D%2010%3B%0D%0A%0D%0A%20%20%20public%20testClass()%0D%0A%20%20%20%20%7B%0D%0A%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20this.t%20%3D%20this.t%20-%201%3B%0D%0A%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20console.log(this.t)%3B%0D%0A%20%20%20%20%7D%0D%0A%7D%0D%0A%0D%0Avar%20obj%20%3D%20new%20testClass()%3B%0D%0Aobj.testClass()%3B%0D%0A)

Maybe you wanted to use a [constructor](https://www.typescriptlang.org/docs/handbook/classes.html) instead?.

Comment: Okay , didn't realize that TestClass() becomes a method and I actually wanted to call constructor. Thanks!!

Answer (score 1):

Seems you missed to call the method of the class:

```
obj.TestClass(); // <---should be called.
```

[Demo@JSBIN](https://jsbin.com/yaximapulu/edit?js,console)

---

Typescript is different than Java where you have to put a same constructor name as the class name.  In Typescript/Javascript you have to use `constructor` keyword. All other functions are treated as class members.

[Demo@Jsbin with constructor](https://jsbin.com/yusatawuxa/edit?js,console)

Comment: Thanks , Just realized that TestClass() is a method and not constructor